# Italian Froyo not show Month Name

Tags: htc-desire, 2.2-froyo

After update my HTC Desire to last Froyo Update, I can't see anymore Month Name or Day Of Week name.
Instead of **January** I see *1* and instead of **Wednesday** I see *2*.
This happens in all my App (even Facebook).
How can I restore the names?
Do I have to root it?

My HTC language system is Italian.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but what do you get if you use a different language? Does changing to English and then back to Italian change things?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know what it is in Italian, but from the home screen, choose "Menu", then "Settings", then "Language & keyboard", then "Select language". I only have two options: English and Spanish. You may have more.

Comment: I've tried and in English i can see month name, but when I switch back to Italian still no name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known "bug" with Android (it is probably intended behavior).  The language, locale, and related settings are all linked and cannot be changed independently.  Google apparently decided that people who read Italian want to see numbers for dates.  I don't believe this was changed in 2.3-gingerbread so I guess there is no fix yet :(