# How to fix Telstra network dropouts on Gingerbread Oxygen ROM?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc-desire, connection-issues, cellular-radio

It's a long shot, but figured i'd give it a go.. I've installed the Oxygen RC6 ROM on my Telstra HTC Desire.  It's pretty much perfect - better than this phone has ever been. It's fast, great to use, no space issues (you can force any app to install to the SD Card which solves my biggest gripe with the desire - minimal internal memory for app storage), and is just all round brilliant.

But there's one problem, and its a doozie.  Every now and then (at least a few times a day) my phone drops its network connection. When i go into settings and try search for networks, it can't find anything.. its as if the radio turns off completely.  Rebooting the phone more often than not fixes it, but still sometimes takes a while to sort itself out.

Its really annoying cos there'll be times where its off and i wont even know it.

The ROM i've installed is this one:
 http://android-roms.net/desire/2011/01/06/oxygen-v2-0-rc6/

I've tried installing a new radio (32.46.00.32U_5.10.05.17_2 on the following page):
 http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=687464

any suggestions how i can fix this?  Try a different radio?  Advice on the best one to try?

Thanks heaps
Greg

Answer (score 1):

Check your APN settings. Make sure it's pointing to the right one, http://www.t-mod.org/?page_id=72

Comment: Thanks i'd already checked them and they were all correct. It was the entire network dropping out, not just the data, so i assume its not related to APN settings (i could be wrong about that)

Answer (score 0):

32.54.00.32U_5.14.05.17 seems to be latest radio; This may help..

Comment: Thanks, i tried every radio i could find, but no go

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found the solution... I upgraded my ROM to the latest version (just released recently):
  http://android-roms.net/desire/2011/01/22/oxygen-v2-0-rc7/

It's now perfectly stable and hasn't dropped out in 12 hours.. lets hope it stays that way :)